# Bouncycastle PGP with multiple files

Tags: encryption, bouncycastle, openpgp

I am developing a tool to encrypt one or multiple files using PGP.
So far, I had no problem to encrypt a single files.
For encrypting several files, I had to resort to zip them in a single file, and then encrypt the single file.
However, I know that Symantec PGP can encrypt several files inside one .PGP file, without having to zip multiple files.
I think this is a more elegant solution, as one does not have to decrypt and unzip (two steps), but only open the PGP file and then select the files.
I have only found examples to encrypt a single files, but no information on how to encrypt several ones.
For the record, I am using BouncyCastle.

Comment: *I know that Symantec PGP can encrypt several files inside one .PGP file,...* How do you know that? What makes you certain the resulting file isn't a zip file?

Comment: Because I have a license for Symantec PGP and I see that they have something called PGP Zip which shows several files

Comment: And you have analyzed the resulting output files to verify they are not zip files? Or you just base your claim on the fact that the file extension is not `.zip`?

Comment: I tried opening it with a compressor, and it is indeed encrypted.

Comment: Have you tried decrypting the .PGP file using e.g. GnuPG to check what the result is?

Answer (score 0):

I fear there is no way around using ZIP compression before encrypting.

While you *could* use multiple Literal Data Packets (one per file) inside your message, [section 11.3 of RFC4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880.html#section-11.3) hints that there can only be a single Literal Data Packet per message. This is also the interpretation of the [OpenPGP Interoperability Test Suite](https://tests.sequoia-pgp.org/#Malformed_messages) which shows that quite a bunch of implementations reject messages with more than one Literal Data Packet.

Going with ZIP is your best option here.